# View not found on my laravel package tests

Tags: php, laravel, package, package-development

I'm trying to add blade directives for my [Laravel package](https://github.com/MahbodHastam/laravel-user-wallet/).

Everything is fine but on testing stage, I'm getting this error:

```
1) MahbodHastam\UserWallet\Tests\Feature\BladeTest::show_user_wallet_balance
InvalidArgumentException: View [userWalletBalance] not found.
```

Should I put `$this->loadViewsFrom(...)` in the service provider?

View path: `/tests/resources/views/userWalletBalance.blade.php`

Test path: `/tests/Feature/BladeTest.php`

I also tried to move the `resources` directory into `Feature` directory (beside the `BladeTest.php`) but got the same error.

This is my code on `BladeTest.php`:

```php
public function show_user_wallet_balance() {
    $wallet = UserWallet::getWallet(wallet_id: 1);

    $this->assertEquals('1000', $this->renderView('userWalletBalance', ['wallet' => $wallet]));
}

protected function renderView($view, $with) {
    Artisan::call('view:clear');

    return trim((string) view($view)->with($with));
}
```

Comment: You can refer to [laravelpackage.com/09-routing.html#views](https://laravelpackage.com/09-routing.html#views) for more information about loading views in your package.

Comment: The docs says about loading views on whole package, but I want to load the views in my tests for testing the blade directives I've added before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it :D

Instead of loading views from files, I used the `InteractsWithViews` trait (which is on the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns` namespace) to render the blade like the code below:

```php
$renderedView = (string) $this->blade("@userWalletBalance($wallet)");

$this->assertEquals('1000', trim($renderedView));
```